# .htaccess subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

Hallo all.

i want to create a .htaccess file if i type subdomain.domain.com can i use ( subdomain ) as a query string and domain.com like domain.

can i get help to this? :)

- tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone visits hello.example.com, you want it to redirect to example.com/?domain=hello.

Please take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/rewriteguide.html, section Virtual User Hosts.

Comment: no not redirect but show in borwser like (hello.example.com) but i get it like ( example.com/?domain=hello )